# Ubuntu 20.04 to Microsoft Active Directory Integration

Tags: ubuntu, directory

I'm having an issue integrating Ubuntu with a Windows Active Directory, the "**Realm Discover**" always fails to find any realm at all.

My DNS server is absolutely fine and I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS trying to integrate with a Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Active Directory Domain.

Any idea's please?

Comment: You say the DNS is fine, but this very strongly suggests a DNS problem. What DNS servers did you use? The computer joining the domain needs to be querying the domain's DNS servers, and they need to be returning valid responses.

Comment: Hi Michael, I did use the domain’s DNS server.

Comment: But are the DNS servers talking to your computer?

Comment: Yes, I have around 12 PC's/Laptops all communicating with the DNS server without issue.